# DDL file only works in debugging mode

Tags: c#

I have a third party dll file which works only when i run my program using visual studio.

It doesn’t work when i run executable file directly from the debug folder.

DLL file is encrypted it could not be modified.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide more details about the DLL file? What is it and what are you trying to achieve in your project?

Comment: To add to the comments from @Papa... What exact error do you see? "It doesn't work" does not give us much to go on ;-)

Comment: How do you know its not working, are you getting any errors? have you checked the log files?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you see the third-party dll in your debug folder where the executable lies? How did you install the executable? Using Nuget or did you download a package from elsewhere? Can you provide us enough detail to reproduce the error on our end - e.g. the third-party library etc.